# Why does my main form take 20+ seconds to become visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I must be missing something obvious, but I simply do not understand why my main form in my Windows Forms Application is taking 20 seconds to show up.  My program is an attempt to take a TPL code example I found in a console application example and make in work in a windows form/gui.  I KNOW the queuing of tasks will take 20 seconds to complete, but does that section of code occur so fast that the form has not had time to finish initialization?  I tried putting a delay right after "InitializeComponent();" in hopes that it would give the form time to come up; and also tried to put just a messagebox after, but still get the same delay after my inserted delay.   There is no form_load method, so there is nothing to check there.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Time the test(s) 
        Stopwatch stoppwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stoppwatch.Start();

        Console.SetOut(new ControlWriter(tb1)); // just redirects console.writeline to the form's textbox "tb1"

        // #################################### job queue ########################################
        var q = new TPLDataflowMultipleHandlers();  //
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

        foreach (var num in numbers)
        {
            F1TimeDelay(2);
            q.Enqueue(num.ToString());
        }

        // Stop the timer and return the elapsed number of milliseconds.
        stoppwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXX  <STATUS> Elapsed time = {0} minutes. XXXXXXXXXX", (int)stoppwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes);
    }
```

As an aside, when the form does finally show up, the text box is full of the messages I was expecting to see from the launched threads  (info like thread id, etc).

F1TimeDelay(2) is a 2 second delay, while the queued jobs are just 10 second long tasks to demonstrate the 10 tasks running in parallel. The numbers sent to the queue end up being job numbers for the 10 tasks.

Comment: *I tried putting a delay right after "InitializeComponent();" in hopes that it would give the form time to come up*. You have one thread here. If you run code on this thread that takes a long time to complete, the UI is blocked, too. If you also add a delay...

Comment: What is the point of the `numbers` enumeration`? Why not just do `for(int  = 1; i < 11; i++)`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what `F1TimeDelay(2);` is, but don't add delays to your code if you want it to run faster.

Comment: @Rufus  the F1TimeDelay(2) is a 2 second delay, while the queued jobs are just 10 second long tasks to demonstrate the 10 tasks running in parallel.  The numbers sent to the queue end up being job numbers for the 10 tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because somewhere between the Constructor and FormShown Event, you are calling code that takes 20+ seconds to complete.

While I can see nothing in the constructor, that is litearlly just the start of the loading process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms

Generally the earliest moment you should retreive any data or do anything else, is in the [Shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown) Event. And even then, a long running operation such as this should be done with some form of Multitasking/Asynchronous operation. You have to figure out what it is, but my guess is for a Disk or Network/Database Access.

If you want to do measurements with a hope of correctnes, you need to start the StopWatch in the Constructor, and only stop/show the result in Shown. And even then your Shown Event might be the 1st one called with the hard/long work comming later, so it might miss whatever causes the issues. Your Stopwatch also does not include the Designer created Elements. The Designer code is executed with InitializeComponents(). Of course with delay on such an order of Magnitude, it should be feasible to just output DateTime.Now regulary.

Comment: I guess I was in such a rush to get this code going that I didn't spend the usual time adding buttons which I usually use to launch tasks and methods.

Answer (score 1):

The form will show sometime after the constructor is done. If you put the long running task queuing code into the constructor, the form wont show until this long running code is done.
Instead add a button to the form and create a click handler for it. put the long running code there. Then the form will show up and you can click the button. But then the form will freeze, because of the task queuing, i guess.

Comment: Yup, I see that now.  No idea why my question is getting downvoted so much, and yet StackOverflow released a page long apology of how it failed to make certain groups feel 'included'.

Comment: @user2972161 it is a bit hard to understand what you are doing with those methods. Maybe a link to the example code could have helped. But I had a similiar problem with a sometimes long running method in the ctor. took a while for me to find out, that sometimes the file i load in is so big, that it delays the wpf window to render.

Comment: F1TimeDelay(2) is a 2 second delay, while the queued jobs are just 10 second long tasks to demonstrate the 10 tasks running in parallel. The numbers sent to the queue end up being job numbers for the 10 tasks.